# if $a_n$ is a convergent series, does $\frac{(-1)^na_n}{n}$ has to converge as well?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $\sum a_n$ be a convergent series. Does $\sum \frac{(-1)^na_n}{n}$ always converge? Prove or show an example to contradict.

I tried both finding an example/proving it, however – I couldn't manage to prove it as it is not known whether $a_n$ is a positive series, thus the usual convergence tests cannot be applied.

I tried finding an example but couldn't find such. Any hint?

Comment: Counter-example: $a_n=\frac {(-1)^{n}} {\ln (n+1)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It is *much* easier for an alternating series to converge than for a series were all the terms have the same sign. And the $(-1)^n$ factor can transform one into the other.